# What is the most secure hybrid cipher suite(Library) possible today?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, key-exchange, hybrid-encryption

What combination of public key cryptography (DH) and symmetric key cryptography is currently available that is (subjectively) as secure as possible over other ciphers (AES,curve448) when security is prioritized over efficiency?

translator user

Comment: The term cipher suite suggests you may be talking of TLS or some such protocol. Is this question about TLS, some other protocol, or a general question about Cryptography?

Comment: Sorry, ciphersuites may not have been the right word. I'm talking about website encrypted communication (https)

Comment: okay, HTTPS means HTTP over TLS :)

Comment: you can consult the following site: https://ciphersuite.info/cs/?sort=desc&tls=tls13&security=secure
You can play around with the TLS version and additional parameters to find what you need.

Comment: Are there any https algorithms that are not TLS?

Comment: No. https by definition is http (which is unencrypted in itself) over a TLS channel. But TLS is one of the most modern, widely adopted and widely implemented protocols probably... so I don't know if I'd worry about that :)

Comment: Isn't it safe to be https with other algorithms?

Comment: I don't understand the question. TLS is not an algorithm, it's a cryptographic protocol. As a cryptographic protocol it offers the use of many cryptographic algorithms in the form of various cipher suites.

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます

Comment: @Amit, Technically, there's HTTP/3, which is HTTP over QUIC, and it's also a kind of HTTPS. I've not read about it in detail, but it may be possible that some QUIC ciphersuites are different from TLS ciphersuites.

Comment: @DannyNiu you're right I guess, but I think of QUIC as TLS over UDP... which would have been done via DTLS but I guess DTLS had problems. QUIC also is  for the record layer so I understand it has to use the same ciphersuites that are determined by the TLS handshake protocol